# Obtener valor de objecto y pasarlo en una url

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

como puedo obtener el valor del objecto `respuesta` y pasarlo a la url `var urld= '/importarexcel/obtenerImport?id=' + respuesta;`

--editado

En `respuesta` obtengo `{obtID: 25}` y solo deseo obtener el numero 25 en este caso para despues pasarlo a la url

```
obtenerMaterias() {
let me = this;

var url = '/importarexcel/id';
    axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var respuesta = response.data;
        //let idImpt = respuesta.obtID.data;

        //Obtener las materias de la malla segun el id
        var urld= '/importarexcel/obtenerImport?id=' + respuesta;

        axios.get(urld).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            var respuesta= response.data;
            me.arrayMaterias = respuesta.materias;
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('FAILUREaaaaa respuesta!!');
            console.log(respuesta);
            console.log('FAILUREaaaaa idImport!!');
            console.log(idImpt);
    });

});
```

}

Comment: Habrá que ver que estructura tiene la respuesta del backend. Podrás compartirla? Siento que está dentro de otro índice.

Comment: ¿acaso no lo estás obteniendo ya del objeto response?

Comment: podrias ser mas especifico , por favor , tienes una variable respuesta , que le retornas un response.data que obtienes despues de que se resuelva la promesa ,  estas seguro que estas recibiendo ya da un dato especifico de esa response.data ?

Comment: @Alberto Siurob lo que obtengo es `{obtID: 25}` y solo quiero obtener el valor en este caso 25 para pasarlo a la url

Comment: a lo mejor y pueda que eso devuelva otra cosa, otra promesa , por ejemplo , y no te este botando el valor que deseas

Comment: Obtienes algun error , para poder ayudarte ? , o algo que nos de un indicio de donde puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que pusiste en los comentarios, tu ID de materia debería ser declarado así

```
var respuesta = response.data.obtID;
```

Comment: si lo que obtiene es ese objeto despues de data , podria ser claramente la respuesta correcta

Comment: si si salio, @Alberto Siurob gracias a vos y los demas, asi si obtengo el valor